# Issue with datetime 'object has no attribute timedelta` calculation Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I'm trying to create a list of dates to add to a dataframe.

The list contains a start date (the last time the dataframe was updates) until today's date.

My code looks like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# get today's date
todays_date = datetime.now()

# read in last date acquired
last_date = old_df['Market Date'].iloc[-1]
```

The last_date starts in `str` format:

```
print(last_date)
2019-01-12
```

I then change to datetime:

```
last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date, '%Y-%M-%d')

# get difference in dates from now since the last update
numdays = todays_date - last_date
days = int(numdays / timedelta(days=1))

date_list = [todays_date - last_date.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, days)]
date_list = [i.strftime('%Y%m%d') for i in date_list]
```

I get the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-64-29fe97665970>", line 35, in <listcomp>
    date_list = [todays_date - last_date.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, days)]
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

The format that the `last_date` is in **is** datetime so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You don't use `timedelta` on `datetime.datetime` objects, you use it directly from the module, i.e. `date_list = [todays_date - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, days)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timedelta()` is a function in the `datetime.datetime` module.

But you're trying to access it as an *attribute* of `datetime.datetime` objects.

`todays_date - timedelta(days=x)` should work just fine.